# Small brownish spots on succulents | how to cure?

Tags: diseases, succulents

What disease/fungi/insect is causing this and how can I get rid of it?

thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first plant Jade, looks like it is receiving too much light Or maybe it's the opposite this could be because of the cold depending on your area. I have the same one. The plant I have was affected by Aphids so I bought neem oil but didn't make the correct balance of water and neem oil, in just two hours 60% of the leaves became black and some had the same spotting as in first picture. And by morning in 8 hours, it lost 80% of the leaves. But the plant recovered in a few days and now there is new growth.

So these leaves with yellow spots will fall off in a few days.